# How to infinitely nest an object polymorphically

Tags: c++, polymorphism, nested

I have a `Config` class that contains a `<string, string>` `map` of data, used for holding configuration keys and values. Sometimes, and I don't know when at compile time, I'd like to be able to access one of the keys inside that object as another (sub-)instance of that object - I want to be able to nest, theoretically infinitely.

The unparsed data would look something like this

```
someKey     = someVal
keysnkrates = "itsastring"
# comments

keyConfig = (
    subKey  = 1
    another = 3.14159
    subKeyConfig = (
        ...inf...
    )
)

otherVals = ...
```

How exactly can I approach parsing something like this without resorting to hack-y C-like methods? I do not want to deal with raw pointers, and I do not want to deal with nulls, however the only solution I've come up with involves tacking on a pointer to the `Config` class, and if it is `!nullptr` then it is a sub-config object.

Comment: It has to be a pointer, possibly hidden, possibly prettified.

Comment: It seems like a linked list should be able to answer your needs no ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use the plain STL map. how do you think (at least) some JSON and XML parsers work in C++?

```
struct Config{
  Data data;
  std::map <std::string,Config> children;
}
```

now inner nest values as you wish:

```
Config config;
config.children["My Inner Config "] = Config(<my data>);
config.children["My Inner Config "].children["My inner inner config"] = Config(<more data>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the best solution to a problem is driven by specifics of the concrete problem. In your case, one of those specifics is how you want to use the resulting data structure in the end (which form of queries should work/work fast?).

In addition to that, sometimes "shortcuts" are possible if you notice specific properties of your problem and exploit them in an opportunistic way.

While the structure of the input data clearly is implying a tree-like data structure, one possible opportunistic shortcut would be if the keys in sub-config data are unique within the set of all occurring keys on all levels. Then you could simply use the map and rely on having no synonym keys. Of course, this would remove the structural information from your data and you would need to decide if you can live with that.

Extending this idea, sometimes you can also avoid implementing trees by means of re-thinking what you use as a key for your map: Right now you use a string. It could as well be a tuple like (key,level) or a concatenation of the keys in a hierarchy to a "path" (e.g. "top/topchild/topchildchild"). Again, it depends on what you will do with the data later on, if this is a viable approach for you.

Last not least, you can also implement trees without a classical tree structure (pointers) if you find a way to push_back() new entries into an array and use array indices to express the parent/child relationships.

Answer (score 0):

If you write this:

```
struct foo {
    int a, b, c;
    struct bar nested_struct;
}
```

Then every time you allocate a new `foo`, you are allocating enough space for the three ints *and* an entire `bar` object, however big that may be.

You can't "infinitely" nest structs/classes in that way because your computer does not have infinite memory.

I don't know what you mean by *raw* pointers, but if you do not wish to create your own linked data structures using pointers and NULLs, then probably you should be using some pre-defined *container class* from a standard library.†

I'm not a C++ programmer, so I don't know what classes and libraries are available, but I'm sure they are out there.

---

† (Edit) Not *probably*.  Every line of code you write eventually becomes a liability.  If you're writing real (commercial) software, then it's always mistake to write more line than you absolutely need to solve the problem at hand.  If there's a library that does what you want, then you should be using it.

Comment: apologies for the miswording, I'm referring to instances of the class. I fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more sophisticated way of doing it (than the accepted answer) is to use `boost::variant` to represent the possible children and the possible data at each node at once.

```
struct Node;

typedef boost::variant<int, std::string, boost::recursive_wrapper<Node>> Value;

struct Node {
    std::map<std::string, Value> children;
};
```

Or something along these lines.
This is nice because if you add several different types to be valid values, you don't need like 10 different children in your various structs, which can generate a lot of boiler plate code in the methods you will want to support.